# Installing imagescanner in windows machine

Tags: python, image-scanner

I want to connect scanner devices in my python program, [imagescanner installation page](https://code.google.com/p/imagescanner/wiki/GettingStarted), in Windows(none so far) said . What does it mean ? Is it cannot use in Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

The comment is regarding the needed requirements for the library to function.

It seems, that on Windows the library does not have any requirements needed

**For Windows**

You could either use pip, if you have it installed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) is how to install pip on Windows.

Or you could use the `setup.py` file. For that you should download the library first and locate to the main folder `imagescanner` in *cmd*. There you type the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: But I don't  understand how to install on windows

Comment: I have made a more complete explanation